# upgrading to ruby 1.9.3 with rvm breaks my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

I have upgraded ruby using the following commands with rvm:

```
rvm get head
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm reload
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Now when I run rails s I get the following error message:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:827:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:261:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:68:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

If I run which ruby, gem environment, and ruby -v I get coherent output. Could anyone help me understand what is going wrong with my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running `gem install rails`?

Using RVM with ruby gems means you can have binaries in your PATH (including the `rails` binary) for gems that are not installed.

This is what your error looks like.

I hope a `bundle install` or `gem install rails` will fix your problem.

Comment: I ran gem install rails, and then bundle install but now when I run rails s my command line gets an error and says there is a syntax error in my user model where there wasn't before.(it is saying that there is an unexpected keyword end at the end of my model, which makes no sense to me) I don't know if there is a conflict with devise, or I am just going crazy.

Comment: I think that's a different problem. If it's an "unexpected end" error it should be in the file the backtrace shows. If it worked in 1.9.2, I can't think of any syntax changes. Try swapping between the 2 and verifying you havent added a syntax error accidentally.

Comment: How do I swap between the two?

Comment: Nevermind I figured out the problem and there was an added comma to one of my files that didn't break in 1.9.2 but did in 1.9.3. I deleted it and now the app runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get your app running again by simply running:

```
$ bundle
```

To install your Gemfile dependencies.  Then you should run rails server with:

```
$ bundle exec rails s
```

It's important to use `bundle exec` in order to ensure the rails command is running from the proper rails gem for your application.

If you'd like more info on this Yehuda Katz has a detailed blog post:
http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/